# Gluon android notification doesn't run

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

How can I use android notifications in gluon?
I used the below code, but the notification doesn't run. Maybe it doesn't find LocalNotification Service?

```
Services.get(LocalNotificationsService.class).ifPresent(service
            -> 
            {
                service.getNotifications().add(new Notification(
                        notificationId, "Sample Notification Text",
                        ZonedDateTime.now().plusSeconds(10), ()
                        -> 
                        {
                            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION,
                                                    "You have been notified!");
                            Platform.runLater(() -> alert.showAndWait());
                }));
    });
```

manifiest:

```
<activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="GluonApplication1" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.gluonapplication1.GluonApplication1"/>
        <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.NotificationActivity"
              android:parentActivityName="javafxports.android.FXActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
                   android:value="javafxports.android.FXActivity"/>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.AlarmReceiver" />
    <service
        android:name="com.gluonapplication1.MyIntentService"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
```

EDIT

Dependencies included in the `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0' 
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.0.1' 
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-local-notifications', version: '3.1.0' 
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5' 
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.15.1' 
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3' 
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what is not working for you? I've just tested your code and it works fine for me (I only removed the service from the manifest). Make sure you add `'local-notifications'` to the list of plugins in your build.gradle file.

Comment: i added compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-local-notifications', version: '3.1.0' but it dont work

Comment: You don't need to add it, the plugin will do it for you. Post your `build.gradle` file, and also check if you have the `charm-down-plugin-local-notifications-android-3.1.0.jar` in your dependencies.

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0'
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm-down-common:2.0.1'
    compile group: 'com.gluonhq', name: 'charm-down-plugin-local-notifications', version: '3.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5'
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.15.1'
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the list of your dependencies, you are not adding the android ones, and you are not using the new `downConfig` configuration to include the Charm Down plugins. Read [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.0.0/#_project_configuration_2) the changes in the build script using the jfxmobile plugin 1.1.0+.

You will need to change your `build.gradle` file at least to include this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'your.main.class.Name'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:4.2.0' 
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.5' 
    desktopRuntime 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.15.1' 
    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3' 
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.1.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'local-notifications', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```